# Find an orthogonal vector using Gram-Schmidit

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**
 1. Find a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which is orthogonal to both $v_1=(1,1,0)$ and $v_2=(1,1,1)$.
 2. Generalize the method of this problem to find a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ orthogonal to the vectors $v_1=(1,1,0,\dots,0), v_2=(1,1,1,0,\dots,0),\dots,v_{n-1}=(1,1,\dots,1,0), \,and v_n=(1,1,\dots,1)$.

$\textbf{Find a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which is orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$.}$

$\begin{vmatrix} \hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1  \end{vmatrix}=(1\cdot 1-0\cdot 1)\hat{i}-(1\cdot 1-0\cdot 1)\hat{j}+(1\cdot 1-1\cdot 1)\hat{k}=\hat{i}-\hat{j}$

So the vector orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$ is $w=(1,-1,0)$.

$\textbf{Find a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ orthogonal to the vectors $v_1, \dots,\,and v_n$}$

I know this involves using Gram-Schmidit process for orthogonalization however I do not recall how to do it for n-dimension.

Comment: Hint: let $v_1$ be a vector that you want to make orthogonal to $v_2$. Try $v_1+\lambda v_2$ and express orthogonality: $(v_1+\lambda v_2)\cdot v_2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily generalize the answer

$$
   w = (1,-1,0,\ldots,0).
$$

This vector is orthogonal to $v_1, \ldots v_n$  since all scalar products with are zero.

Comment: How do you get that answer?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown, Second step for Gram-Schmidt process gives this vector and then doesn't change it.

Comment: Okie dokie. I will try to work it out.